# string multiple ssh commands together, but delay dns lookup until on remote host

Tags: linux, ssh, dns

I am able to connect from home to a server at work (`server A`) via an ssh server exposed to the internet.

I need to run a command on a server in another office (`server C`), which is not directly accessible from `server A`.

However, there is an intermediate server (`server B`), which `server A` can access, and from which `server C` is accessible.

```
+------+   +----------+   +----------+   +----------+
| home |---| server A |---| server B |---| server C |
+------+   +----------+   +----------+   +----------+
```

I know that I can run a command on a remote server using ssh as follows:

```
ssh hostname command
```

As such, I tried to string multiple ssh commands together

```
ssh server_A ssh server_B ssh server_C command
```

However, I get an error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname server_B: Name or service not known
```

This seems to suggest the dns lookup is happening locally, rather than on the remote server.

**Note:**

I tried stringing multiple ssh commands together using hosts which my local dns server can resolve, and that worked, which suggests if I can solve my dns lookup problem, I should be able to achieve what I want.

**Question:**

How can I string multiple ssh commands together, but force the name lookup to only occur on the remote server on which the next command is due to be run?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell the name resolution is done on the remote:

- set up my local `/etc/hosts` to give a name to a server of mine out in the cloud
- `ping server` pings the server so local DNS resolution works
- `ssh server ping server` says `ping: unknown host server`
- `ssh server ssh server` says `ssh: Could not resolve hostname server: Name or service not known`

So the name resolution of the commands in the strings isn't done locally. If you can't get the address it is because the remote host itself cannot resolve the name. To convince yourself, starts a SSH prompt on serverA and see if it can resolve serverB (`ping` or else).